# Binding issue with DataTemplate?

Tags: c#, binding

I have some XAML code in Window.Resources:

```
        <ContextMenu x:Key="ParentContextMenu">
            <MenuItem Header="MenuItem..." Command="{Binding SomeCommand}"/>
        </ContextMenu>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ChildDataTemplate" DataType="{x:Type System:String}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="ParentDataTemplate" DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:IParentViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Agents}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ChildDataTemplate}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" ContextMenu="{StaticResource ParentContextMenu}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ServerName}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

and then

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ParentDataTemplate}"/>
```

Why is SomeCommand not bound to the Context menu item?

I am sure that DataContext contains a ViewModel because other commands are working well. Any ideas please?

Comment: didn't know you could bing DateTemplates :P

Comment: Do you get any error messages in the output window when you run the app? Maybe some binding error on SomeCommand?

Answer (score 0):

Any problem with this XAML.
So, I think you need to ckeck your class that implements `IParentViewModel`.
1) To my mind, your SomeCommand like `SomeCommand : ICommand`. Verify that access modifier is public(**public** `class SomeCommand : ICommand`)

2) Verify that access modifier of command property is public
(e.g.

```
  public SomeCommand SomeCommand
  {
        get { return _someCommand; }
            set
            {
                _someCommand = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SomeCommand");
            }
        }
```

3) Verify that you have created command instance (`private SomeCommand _someCommand = new SomeCommand();`)

Also,do that in case if you have dependency property instead.
Hope it helps.